Complex integrals that look like they agree, differ by sign (according to Mathematica)
Consider the integral
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{dz}{1-z^2 +i0^+},$$
I would assume it to agree with the integral
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{dz}{(1-z+i0^+)(1+z+i0^+)}. $$
However, according to Mathematica the former integral evaluates to
$i\pi/2$ and the latter to $-i\pi/2$, so against my expectation they differ by sign.
I computed the second integral by hand and obtained the same result, however I don't know how to verify the first, since I only considered the second integral in order to compute the first.
I ran the following two codes in Mathematica
Integrate[1/(1 - x^2 + I*\[Epsilon]), {x, 0, Infinity}] /. {\[Epsilon] -> 0}
Integrate[1/((1 + x + I*\[Epsilon])*(1 - x + I*\[Epsilon])), {x, 0, Infinity}] /. {[Epsilon] -> 0}

what is $i0^+$?

Wolfram alpha suggests the former is also $-i\pi/2$

In retrospect, this question is more suitable for the Mathematica SE

As given, your Integrate inputs produce ConditionalExpressions that, for some reason, do not include the case of \[Epsilon] being zero:
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{1-x^2+i\epsilon} = -\frac\pi{2\sqrt{-1-i\epsilon}} \text{ if } \Re \epsilon \neq 0 \lor \Im \epsilon \ge1$$
Now, when you execute the ReplaceAll (the shorthand /.) and plug in $\epsilon=0$, Mathematica will return Undefined.
But enforcing the condition that $\epsilon$ is positive gives the same result anyway,
Integrate[..., {x, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> \[Epsilon] > 0]


$$-\frac\pi{2\sqrt{-1-i\epsilon}}$$

However, executing ReplaceAll again may lead to spurious results due to the built-in choice of branch of the Sqrt function. Instead, opt for Limit:
Integrate[1/(1 - x^2 + I*\[Epsilon]), {x, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> \[Epsilon] > 0];
Limit[%, \[Epsilon] -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"]


$$-\frac\pi{2\sqrt{-1-i\epsilon}}$$

Integrate[1/((1 - x + I \[Epsilon]) (1 + x + I \[Epsilon])), {x, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> \[Epsilon] > 0];
Limit[%, \[Epsilon] -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"]


$$\frac\pi{2(i-\epsilon)}$$

Now both integrals converge to $-\dfrac{i\pi}2$. That's clear from the latter output. For the former, Mathematica assumes the branch with $\arg z\in(-\pi,\pi]$, so $-1-i\epsilon$ will have argument approaching $-\pi$, hence the argument of $\sqrt{-1-i\epsilon}$ approaches $-\dfrac\pi2$, and thus
$$\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+} \frac{-\pi}{2\sqrt{-1-i\epsilon}} = -\frac\pi{2\sqrt{\lvert-1\rvert}\, e^{i/2 (-\pi)}} = -\frac{i\pi}2$$

This is the answer, thank you! You are right in your comment that this question was posted on the wrong stackExchange. I should be more careful when taking limits / using Mathematica in general.

The two Integrals are not Same.
The Second Integral is :
Integrate[1/(1 - x^2 + 2*I*\[Epsilon] - \[Epsilon]^2), {x, 0, Infinity}] /. {\[Epsilon] -> 0}
Here , even the $\epsilon$ value is $2i\epsilon-\epsilon^2$ which will not match what you want.

Shouldn't it go to the same limit as $\epsilon\to0$?

Let us use $E=\epsilon$ , $E=i\epsilon$ , $E=2i\epsilon-\epsilon^2$ , $E=\cdots$ in the Denominator , then I am currently thinking that there is no unique limit when that $E$ tends to $0$ , @J.W.Tanner , it might depend on the "Direction" in general !

Checking with Wolfram Online Tool : "integrate dz/(1-z^2+0.000000001i) from z=0 to z=infinity" gives $-$ value , while : "integrate dz/(1-z^2-0.000000001i) from z=0 to z=infinity" gives $+$ value , @J.W.Tanner , moreover "integrate dz/(1-z^2+0.000000001) from z=0 to z=infinity" gives $0$ , to indicate that "Direction" can/will matter.

The other answer based on Mathematica Syntax confirms my "Suspicion" , that "Direction" to approach $0$ matters to get the limit in general , @J.W.Tanner , though Mathematica has been forced to use a "Certain Direction" to get matching values.
